# convert list of integers in string format to list of integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which looks like below

```
lis = '[-3.56568247e-02 -3.31957154e-02\n  7.04742894e-02\n  7.32413381e-02\n  1.74463019e-02]' (string type)
```

'\n' is also there in the list.
I need to convert this to actual list of integers

```
lis = [-3.56568247e-02,-3.31957154e-02 ,7.04742894e-02 ,7.32413381e-02, 1.74463019e-02]  (list of integers)
```

I am doing the functionality, but it is failing

```
import as
res = ast.literal_eval(lis)
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `re.findall` along with a list comprehension:

```py
lis = '[-3.56568247e-02 -3.31957154e-02  7.04742894e-02  7.32413381e-02\n  1.74463019e-02]'
output = [float(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[+-]\d+)?', lis)]
print(output)

# [0.0356568247, 0.0331957154, 0.0704742894, 0.0732413381, 0.0174463019]
```

Comment: just updated the code @Tim. sorry for the delay

Comment: Check the updated answer.  For future reference, please avoid changing your question after multiple users have given answers.

Comment: ++ very good use of *optional* non-capture groups

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
[int(i) for i in lis.strip("[]").split(" ")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You risk getting 1000 ways to do this.

This is a quick and easy way using only basic methods:

```
lis = '[1 2 3 4 5 77]'

elements = lis.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(' ')

my_ints = [int(e) for e in elements]

print(my_ints)
```

Comment: just updated the code...sorry for the delay